# C# CSV to JSON per row

Tags: c#, arrays, json, csv, split

Major Edit: I am doing a bad job of explaining :(

I have two classes:

```
public class UserDefinitions// a list of 'Items', each'group of items belong to a user. I handle User logic elsewhere, and it works flawlessly.  
    {
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    }
public class Item //the User definitions. A user could have 1 or 15 of these. They would all be a single 'line' from the CSV file.
    {

       public string definitionKey { get; set; }
       public string defName { get; set; }
       public string defValue { get; set; }

    }
```

Which I wanna build with a CSV File. I build this CSV File, so I make it using the same parameters every time.

I run SQL on my company's DB to generate results like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzNc9.png

Then I read the file like so:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var userData = new UserDefinitions();
        var csvList = new List<Item>();
        string json = "";
        string fPath = @"C:\test\csvTest.csv";
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fPath);
        Console.WriteLine(lines);
        List<string> udata = new List<string>(lines);
        foreach (var line in udata)
        {
            string[] userDataComplete = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);// this cleans any empty cells from the CSV  

            csvList.Add(new Item { definitionKey = userDataComplete[1], defName = userDataComplete[2], defValue = userDataComplete[3] });
        }

        json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(csvList); //everything below is for debugging/tracking progress  
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.ReadKey();

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\test\\testjson.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(json);
        sw.Close();

     }

  }
```

This ALMOST does what I want. The output json is from the first 'column' of the csv data

[{"definitionKey":"uuid1","defName":"HairColor","defValue":"Brown"},{"definitionKey":"uuid1","defName":"HairColor","defValue":"Blonde"},{"definitionKey":"uuid1","defName":"HairColor","defValue":"Blue"}]

When using the screen shot as an example, the *wanted* output should be

[{"attributeDefinitionKey":"uuid1","name":"HairColor","value":"Brown"},{"definitionKey":"uuid2","defName":"FreckleAmount","defValue":"50"}]
[{"attributeDefinitionKey":"uuid1","name":"HairColor","value":"Blonde"},{"definitionKey":"uuid2","defName":"FreckleAmount","defValue":"null"}]
[{"attributeDefinitionKey":"uuid1","name":"HairColor","value":"Blue"},{"definitionKey":"uuid3","defName":"Tattoos","defValue":"5"}]

I can't pick out certain aspects at will, or apply them to Items. For example there maybe 10 users or 5000 users, but the definitionKey will always be the [1], and adding '3' will get every subsequent defintionKey. Just like the defName will always be in the [2] spot and adding 3 will get every subsequent defName if there are any, this is all per line.

I know I have to add some +3 logic, but not quite sure how to incorporate that. Maybe a for loop? a nested for loop after a foreach loop? I feel I am missing something obvious!

Thanks again for any help

Comment: Does the users have multiple lines in the CSV file? and do you want all the  "items" sorted by the users they belong to?
And does each entry in the csv file have varying amount of columns?

Comment: One user, will take only one row.   

all 'items' in a single row belong to one user   

and in one CSV document there could be a total of 15 Things (each with an id, name, value) user 1 could have a value under all of them, user 2 could have a value for 10 of the things, user 3 could have only 5 Things with values..but all are available. If they dont have a value for Thing 1, then the cell would be blank.  
Am I being clear, or super confusing?

Comment: very confusing, you have to show or give an example of what the CSV actually looks like. 
Because you are saying that a user has one row and that an item has a single row. So are they mixed up? 
Or do you mean that the CSV is all rows representing items with a column with a User Id

Comment: Sorry its confusing! Here is a screenshot of an example, figured it'd be easiest... http://i.imgur.com/gS1UJot.png

Answer (score 1):

This reads the csv line for line and converts each row to json, while adapting to the change in the amount of columns.

This only works if the CSV follows your rules:
one userId and
x amount of "Things" with 3 columns per "Thing".

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var file = new StreamReader(@"C:\test\csvTest.csv");
        string line;
        var itemsJson = new List<string>();
        file.ReadLine();
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var fields = line.Split(',');


            sb.Append(GetKeyValueJson("UserId", fields[0]));
            for (var i = 1; i < fields.Length; i += 3)
            {
                var x = (i + 3) / 3;
                sb.Append(GetKeyValueJson($"Thing {i + x} ID", fields[i]));
                sb.Append(GetKeyValueJson($"Thing {i + x} ID", fields[i + 1]));


                sb.Append(i + 3 == fields.Length
                    ? GetKeyValueJson($"Thing {i + x} ID", fields[i + 2], true)
                    : GetKeyValueJson($"Thing {i + x} ID", fields[i + 2]));
            }

            itemsJson.Add(WrapJson(sb.ToString()));
        }

        var json = WrapItems(itemsJson);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string GetKeyValueJson(string id, string value, bool lastPair = false)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append('"');
        sb.Append(id);
        sb.Append('"');
        sb.Append(':');
        sb.Append('"');
        sb.Append(value);
        sb.Append('"');
        if (!lastPair)
            sb.Append(',');

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static string WrapJson(string s)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append('{');
        sb.Append(s);
        sb.Append('}');

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static string WrapItems(List<string> jsonList)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append('"');
        sb.Append("Items");
        sb.Append('"');
        sb.Append(':');
        sb.Append('[');
        sb.Append(jsonList.Aggregate((current, next) => current + "," + next));
        sb.Append(']');

        return WrapJson(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

It's not pretty and sorting would be tough, but it should adapt to the column amount as long as it is in 3's.

Comment: Thanks!

I need the fields,or 'Things' to be adaptive. Sometimes there are 3 things, sometimes there are 15 'things', each with a id, name , value.

i was thinking maybe reading the csv per *row*, then assigning the setters at each row with a for loop

Comment: Maybe some Async.  
  
Must dive deeper captain!

Comment: @B_happy_chap I have edited the solution, this should accept any number of "Things" as long as each "Thing" have 3 columns. Unfortunately you won't get objects of classes, just strings in json format.

Comment: Hmm close. I think I am being shitty at explaining my issue. Probably the same reason I can't find what I am looking for! 

I have a json converter, using json.net.

Using a bit of your code, I have modified mine. I'll reedit the main post to reflect the changes.

Comment: I only say close, because sr uses so much memory, and I may process a 10 row document, or 15000 row document, with up to 45-50 columns. 'ReadAllLines' puts the content into memory and allows faster processing, especially since after i master the solution, I am gearing it to enterprise code.